# Visual Studio cant find or acces MYSQL data base

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm working on a code that acces a database from mysql gests information and uses it somewhere else, but whenever I try to acces this database i get the error message "unknown database (nameofdatabase)", Ichecked that the name is correct and it is, and what really throws me off this same code worked in another computer, with a copy of the same database with no issue what so ever but not in this computer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace STrailers.db
{
    public class BaseDatos
    {
        private string Host;
        private int Port;
        private string NameDB;
        private string User;
        private string Password;

        private MySqlConnection TheConnection;

        public BaseDatos()
        {
            this.Host = "127.0.0.1";
            this.Port = 3306;
            this.NameDB = "pruebas";
            this.User = "root";
            this.Password = "admin";
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            string cadenaConexion =
                "server=" + Host + ";"
                + "uid=" + User + ";"
                + "pwd=" + Password + ";"
                + "database=" + NameDB + ";";

            Console.WriteLine("conectando a" + cadenaConexion);

            TheConnection = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
            TheConnection.Open();

        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            TheConnection.Close();
            TheConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried creating other databases with diferent names all to no avail.

Comment: have you verified the connectionstring? user name, password, dbname.....

Comment: You should use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead of haphazzardly concatenating user-supplied strings.

Comment: On the other computer you have mySQL server running? the same database created on the that server? Are you able to connect to that database using MySQL workbench or mysql command?

Comment: I have verified the connection string, make sure all the information is correct multiple times, and it is @viveknuna

Comment: I know it's not the best, doing it all hard-coded, but for the purposes of this database it's ok to have it like this @Dai

Comment: The other computer has an identical copy of the database, name and all, and yes I can access the database using workbench in both computers with no issue @Chetan

Comment: Ok, I'll try changing it to it, hopefully is not very complicated, I still don't understand why this same code works on a different computer thou@Dai

Comment: After changing to `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` it made no difference it still is unable to access the database, the code still says it's unknown, even thou all the variables are correct @Dai

Comment: Show us a screenshot of MySQL Workspace's Schema Explorer when you're connected to it successfully.

Comment: @user9938 How is that relevant to this question?

Comment: I would suggest you connect with a known good tool using the same connection string (as much as possible) and make sure the computer can reach the server. It could very easily be a network issue.

Comment: I see you defined the port but not used it in the connection string. Have you tried including the port Port=3306;

Comment: What OS the computer is running. Are you using .NET or .NET Framework? Which version? Open `MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client`, login and type: `show databases;`.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: [Windows Platform Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-restrictions.html) and [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).